# Need to build older linux kernel (2.4) from source and reflect the same in existing grub config

Tags: linux, partitioning, grub, linux-kernel, patch

I need help in setting up my machine as below in various partitions:
(Dell precision, 64 bit laptop)

1)Centos 64 bit latest, this would be my main working partition and OS

2)Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 32 bit (for some legacy project compatibility, I need this also with me)

3)2.4.24 Linux kernel patched with RT Linux patch (I have to apply patch)  (Planning to use Arch Linux, but could not get immediate documentation how to, any other way is welcome too even simple command line setup should do)

4) Other additional Linux partitions I want to add later for some more experimental purpose like LFS, arch Linux etc

Kindly help me in getting above setup done. 
I had actually setup Centos, Ubuntu 32 bit 14.04 LTS but while trying to install Arch Linux, my bootloader broke and landing to grub console on rescue. 
I am basically experienced user and built kernel earlier and used commands to get that updated in grub, but always using Ubuntu only, now I am facing trouble setting up with multi *nix OS boot... where one of them needs kernel patched image.

A setup with /boot containing all images would also be fine. I havent ever earlier done this way, always installed multi boot where all are Ubuntu variants and could manage to setup. Each partition has separate boot directory this way. Any better alternatives and how to do that would be great.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Get a closer look at grub installation on Archlinux :
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB

You need to set up properly grub to scan for all the installed distro and kernels.

The easiest workaround for you should be using virtual machines with virtualbox or qemu instead of dealing with multiboot difficulties (Mostly with archlinux FYI :
"Arch Linux is a versatile, and simple distribution designed to fit the needs of the competent Linux® user.")
https://www.archlinux.org/about/

Comment: I am experimenting to setup low latency desktop for which I am trying archlinux and I dont think latency/embedded testing will be appropriate on VMs. Other partitions/OSes also are needed for similar reason because of which I am not using VMs. Only Centos is the one which I want as a full fledged general purpose OS for me.

Comment: That apart, I think I did mistake while installing grub, that I used /dev/sda1 instead of /dev/sda. Also, this is almost first time am using non ubuntu installation after over 10 years earlier when I used redhat and am not much into boot partition, bios boot, grub update etc.... so not really sure what caused the failure. Redoing the setup now anyways with /boot separately and unified for all partitions